# WPF Datagrid ItemSource + ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, datagrid, observablecollection

I've a Datagrid that shows all the Data from an ObservableCollection.But I just want to show the first 10 elements in the Datagrid. Can you please help?

Comment: add your code, then sure someone can help

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using MVVM.. You can try using collection view source..

```
 observableCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
 Items = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(observableCollection.Take(10));
```

Where "Items" is property in your viewmodel and "ItemsSource" for your data grid..

```
public ICollectionView Items { get; set; }
```

You may have to include couple of namespaces in your viewmodel

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Data;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, right now Im not using MVVM, it's code behind. Im new in WPF. But my next step would be to use MVVM

Comment: if you are not using MVVM you can still use the above solution... change you code behind as above and assign "Items" as item source for your data grid

Comment: But this solution is not observable ... as in if someone adds an element in first 10 indices of the source observable collection, they wont update on the GUI. Use `CollectionView.Filter = Func<object, bool>(item => sourceCollection.IndexOf(item) < 9)`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your DataGrid is dg.
You can try :

```
int nbV = 10; //number you want
ItemCollection ic = new ItemCollection();
for(int k = 0; k < nbV; k++)
   {
      ic.Add(dg.Items[k]);
   }

dg.ItemsSource = ic.DefaultView;
```